# cannot find -lplot - fedora

Tags: c++, gnuplot, fedora, linker-errors

I installed gnuplot using `sudo yum install gnuplot` on terminal. And I have a cpp file, it use gnuplot. I compile without error.On linking,the error occurs.

Compile : `g++ -c plot.cpp`
Link : `g++ -o exe plot.o -lplot`

Code :

```
int main()
{

FILE *pipe = popen("gnuplot -persist", "w");

// set axis ranges
fprintf(pipe,"set xrange [0:11]\n");
fprintf(pipe,"set yrange [0:]\n");

int b = 5;int a;

// to make 10 points
std::vector<int> x (10, 0.0); // x values
std::vector<int> y (10, 0.0); // y values

for (a=0;a<10;a++) // 10 plots
{
    x[a] = a;
    y[a] = 2*a;// some function of a
    fprintf(pipe,"plot '-'\n");
    // 1 additional data point per plot
    for (int ii = 0; ii <= a; ii++) {
        fprintf(pipe, "%d %d\n", x[ii], y[ii]); // plot `a` points
    }

    fprintf(pipe,"e\n");    // finally, e
    fflush(pipe);   // flush the pipe to update the plot
    usleep(1000000);// wait a second before updating again
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: But your program doesn't actually *use* any functions from any plot library, all it uses is standard functions (either of C or of POSIX), so there's no need to link with any plot library. All your program does is execute an external program, and if it's in the path then it will run.

Answer (score 0):

Add a flag `-L /where/ever/you/have/the/lib -lplot`to specify where `libplot.a` resides, if you need that lib at all. From your code however it seems that you're just feeding data into `gnuplot` but don't link against any `libplot.a`.

Comment: I don't have libplot.a. I open /lib folder,it isnot there.

Comment: @holazollil The `/lib` directory should only contain system libraries, and the linker will automatically look in it as well as `/usr/lib`. You need to specify where *you* have installed the library (you *have* installed it, haven't you?).

Comment: I look /usr/lib but not there.

Comment: Are you sure you need that lib? Your code doesn't suggest it (at least the part that is shown). What happens when you link without the lib?